# How to invoke the buffer list in Emacs

Tags: emacs, buffer

I usually type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `buffer-menu` to switch buffers in Emacs. How can I do this with a shorter command? Its quite a long string to type.

Thanks!

Comment: As a more general point: C-h f _function name_ will bring up help for the function, including any keys it may be bound to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You can use `C-x b` to change buffers. You have to enter the first few letters of the buffer name, and of course you can use completion. If you press `TAB` (the most useful key in Emacs), a list of (matching) buffers appears. You can click in this list to switch to a buffer.
- You can bind `buffer-menu` to a key. Pick a key that's not used for another command — let's say `f12` — and add the following line to the file `~/.emacs`:

  ```
  (global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'buffer-menu)
  ```
- [There are many other interfaces to changing buffers in Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers), and they can be significantly more efficient than `C-x b` and `C-x C-b`. Since this tends to be a very personal choice, I recommend you experiment with a few and keep the one(s) you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why did you roll back the edit I made?

Comment: @itsjeyd `C-x b` and the like is the standard notation for key bindings in Emacs. Please stick to that notation when dealing with Emacs keys. Use `kbd` tags when refering to actual keyboard keys, but use it properly: for example, pressing `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>` then `<kbd>B</kbd>` on the keyboard (I'm showing the raw HTML here as the HTML tag can't be used in a comment) generates the Emacs key sequence `\`C-x b\``.

Comment: Interesting. I always assumed that a sentence like "Press `C-x b` to change buffers" *was* referring to (a sequence of) actual keyboard keys being pressed. I wouldn't use the `<kbd>` notation in a context that refers to Elisp code. Is there a Meta SO post (or an entry in the Help section I might have overlooked) that defines these standards? Again, just curious, as I have seen a number of posts that utilize the available markup options in a different (but consistent) way than you are suggesting.

Comment: @itsjeyd No idea about a meta post. The example in the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html) is `<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>`, not `<kbd>ctrl-alt-del</kbd>`, but that's not very conclusive. But having written several posts where I explained the difference between physical keystrokes and application keys (e.g. modifier keys, ESC/Alt, …), I can attest that the distinction is useful.

Answer (score 6):

C-x C-b

As stated [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/emacs18/emacs_20.html#SEC110)

Comment: Yes thanks, the thing I dont like with it though is that the screen is split in two parts.

Answer (score 4):

I'd highly recommend switching to a mode designed for efficient buffer switching.

If your version of Emacs is recent enough (22+):

```
M-x ido-mode
```

and then:

```
C-x b
```

to switch buffers, with incremental substring matching, `C-s` and `C-r` rotate forward and backwards through the matches.

If you have an older version of Emacs, it should have:

```
M-x iswitchb-mode
```

and then, as with `ido-mode`:

```
C-x b
```

opens up the minibuffer to let you choose the buffer to switch to.

Answer (score 2):

Bind <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd> to `buffer-menu`.  There is no sense leaving it bound to `list-buffers`.  `list-buffers` is just a eunuch version of `buffer-menu`. ;-)

And you might want to try this: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferMenuPlus

Answer (score 1):

Try bs-show (in my opinion a way better than C-x C-b). You can bind it to F9 by adding this to .emacs:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'bs-show)
```