# How can I more easily switch between buffers in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I've recently started using emacs and I'm enjoying using it for the most part. The only thing I'm not enjoying, is switching between buffers. I often have a few buffers open and I've grown tired of using `C-x b` and `C-x C-b`, are there any packages that make switching between buffers easier? I've looked into [emacs wiki on switching buffers](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers#toc1) and I'd appreciate insight/feedback on what are are using/enjoying. Thanks.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813734/buffer-switching-in-emacs/6814873#6814873 cover this?

Comment: I almost never use switch-to-buffer ^xb. // I often use buffer-menu (which I have bound to ^bm - I have my own, highly non-standard, keybindings). // I also have commands that switch to particular types of buffers, e.g.  ^ss to switch to shell buffers, using a completing read on the foo part of a buffer name like *shell*<foo>.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### UPDATE: `iswitchb-mode` is obsolete in Emacs >= 24.4, replaced by `ido`.

All of the features of `iswitchdb` are now provided by `ido`. Ross provided a link to [the documentation](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) in his answer. You can activate with the following in your `.emacs` (or use the customization interface as Ross suggests):

```el
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode 'buffers) ;; only use this line to turn off ido for file names!
(setq ido-ignore-buffers '("^ " "*Completions*" "*Shell Command Output*"
               "*Messages*" "Async Shell Command"))
```

By default, `ido` provides completions for buffer names and file names. If you only want to replace the features of `iswitchb`, the second line turns off this feature for file names. `ido` will ignore any buffers that match the regexps listed in `ido-ignore-buffers`.

The behaviour described below for `iswitchb-mode` applies equally to `ido` for switching buffers.

### iswitchb-mode (Emacs < 24.4)

`iswitchb-mode` replaces the default `C-x b` behaviour with a very intuitive buffer-switching-with-completion system. There are more sophisticated options, but I've never needed more than this.

After you hit `C-x b`, you are presented with a list of all buffers. Start typing the name of the buffer you want (or part of its name), and the list is narrowed until only one buffer matches. You don't need to complete the name, though, as soon as the buffer you want is highlighted hitting enter will move you to it. You can also use `C-s` and `C-r` to move through the list in order.

You can turn it on by default with this in your .emacs:

```el
(iswitchb-mode 1)
```

You can also tell it to ignore certain buffers that you never (or very rarely) need to switch to:

```el
(setq iswitchb-buffer-ignore '("^ " "*Completions*" "*Shell Command Output*"
               "*Messages*" "Async Shell Command"))
```

Comment: I personally use `ido-mode` which I assume is very similar.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `C-x <right>` (`next-buffer`) and `C-x <left>` (`previous-buffer`) to cycle around in the buffer ring. You could bind `S-<right>` and `S-<left>` to these functions. (`S` is the "super-key" or windows-key). This way you can save some keystrokes.

Moreover, note that `C-x b` has a default entry, i.e. it displays a standard value (most of the time this is the previously viewed buffer), so that you don't always need to enter the buffer name explicitly.

Another nice trick is to open separate windows using `C-x 2` and `C-x 3`. This displays several buffers simultaneously. Then you can bind `C-<tab>` to `other-window` and get something similar to tabbed browsing.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 8):

`M-x customize-group ido` then set `Ido Mode` to `Turn on both buffer and file` and set `Ido Everywhere` to `on`.  Then click the `Save for future sessions` button at the top and enjoy ido magic for both files and buffers.  Read [the docs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) to get a sense of how to use ido.

Also, take a look at [`smex`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Smex).

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I got a bit lost in Ido's doc about adding files from a file system tree to the completion list. Do you have same hints about how to set that up?

Comment: @danza Not sure what you mean.  With the options above, completion lists for finding files via `C-x C-f` are populated automatically.

Comment: My question did not make sense because i misunderstood the features provided by Ido. I thought that Ido would provide a way to find files at arbitrary depths. Eventually i settled on `helm-projectile`. Anyway, your answer allowed me to set up Ido really fast

Answer (score 5):

1. `ido-mode` provides an efficient way to switch buffers.
2. `ibuffer` is best for managing all opened buffers.
3. `anything` is good for selecting an interested thing from different
   sources. (for eg: a single key can be used to switch to another
   buffer or to open recently closed file or to open a file residing
   in the same directory or ... anything you want ... )

Answer (score 2):

If you've looked at the Emacs Wiki, you probably have all this information already, but here are a few other relevant Q&As:

- [Emacs: help me understand file/buffer management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145332)
- [Buffer switching in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813734)
- [How to invoke the buffer list in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505997)

My toolkit consists of ibuffer, windmove+framemove, winner-mode, and a [custom binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133181/emacs-tab-between-buffers/4160521#4160521) to make <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> and <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> less of a hassle to use.

Answer (score 2):

I have mapped the "§"-key to 'buffer-list and I find it to be very efficient.

Comment: I do something similar on a Microsoft keyboard, binding the 'menu' key (between the right-hand Alt & Ctrl) to `ibuffer`, which I find tremendously convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I've started using anything for a couple of days and I'm really liking it:  **http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything** .

Emacs-fu has an good intro to anything:  **http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2011/09/finding-just-about-anything.html**

Answer (score 0):

- My favourite function for this is `helm-mini` which is part of [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm).

As other helm functions, it allows incremental narrowing of the selection. It also searches your recently visited buffers, which is a really nice way to re-open a buffer. Helm can be a little surprising at first and as a new Emacs user, I found it visually overwhelming and I preferred `ido` or `ibuffer` which have been suggested in other replies. But now I absolutely love it and use it all the time for countless things.

- Something that I realized by accident and that can be useful:

`mouse-buffer-menu` is by default bound to `<C-mouse-1>` (Control key + mouse left click) and opens a popup with a list of the current buffers.