# Selecting different buffers in the buffer menu

Tags: emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I more easily switch between buffers in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394289/how-can-i-more-easily-switch-between-buffers-in-emacs)

```
GNU Emacs 24.1.1
```

Hello,

When I want to switch buffers I use the following C-x C-b if I have many buffers active. But I find it very inefficient.

And it will display a lists of open buffers in the next buffer (I don't like this in the next buffer). Normally I have 4 buffers open at the same time.

Using the above I will then have to put the cursor (C-o) to get focus in the buffer-list buffer, when scroll up or down to select the buffer I want.

Sometimes I use C-x-b if I don't have many active buffers. However, I always have many.

However, I am looking for something then will open up a small buffer with a list of buffers (the minimum needed - just enough to show all buffers), and will automatically have focus. I scroll to select the buffer I want. And it will appear in the buffer I had focus on before I open the list of buffers. The buffer-list will then disappear.

Does anyone know of anything like this to make switching buffers easier.

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from `ido-mode`, good buffer switching solutions are:

1. Plain-old <kbd>C-x b</kbd> + [icomplete-mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/IcompleteMode)
2. [ibuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode) - just rebind <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd> to `ibuffer` to see it in action:

   (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
3. [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) - an incremental narrowing and selection framework useful to find just about anything (buffers included).

Answer (score 3):

Check [ido-mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings). C-x C-b is the old way.

```
The ido lets you interactively do things with buffers and files.
```