# Open new file in a new gui window or by splitting the window

Tags: emacs, window, file-browser

How can emacs open a new file in a new gui window? And how can it be made to open by splitting a window?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking two questions, although it's not really clear. As far as more efficiently cycling through the buffer ring, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394289/how-can-i-more-easily-switch-between-buffers-in-emacs

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Emacs refers to gui windows as 'frames', and the partitions with a frame are called 'windows'.

You can open a file in a new frame with `C-x 5 f`. You can open a file in a different window in the same frame with `C-x 4 f`.

Comment: I like `'new-frame` and `'other-frame` to switch between frames better.

Comment: In my case `C-x 4 f` opens the file in the other existing window in that frame. Is there a way to open the file in a `new` window in the same frame. So say, I have 2 windows, I want to open the file in a third window?

Comment: `C-x 2 C-x C-f` or `C-x 3 C-x C-f`. If the combo is too long you can save it as a macro and bind it to something shorter.