# How to get tabs in emacs

Tags: emacs, tabs

is there a mode that gives tabs to emacs. I lost lots of time **navigating between buffers**. I need to get a view which shows me the different buffers.

Comment: There's a show buffers combo.

Comment: See the Emacs Wiki category page for [buffer switching](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryBufferSwitching).

Comment: See also [How can I more easily switch between buffers in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394289)

Comment: Questions about *using* programs such as Emacs are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they are specific to programming modes; you may be able to get help on [emacs.se] or [su].  If your question is about programming Emacs, then please [edit] to include a [mcve] of the Lisp or C code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

For tabs, I recommend [tabbar-mode](https://github.com/dholm/tabbar).  It is a minor mode that should provide the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I use [elscreen](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Elscreen) for this, even if they are not "real" tabs like in other apps (not draggable, no close button, and not "one buffer per tab" concept, we create tabs when we want). But it's enough for me to organize my work in different views.

I also like the hydra you'll see on the wiki and I bound other keys to switch between tabs more naturally:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-prior>") 'elscreen-previous)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-next>") 'elscreen-next)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'elscreen-next) ;; except in org
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-iso-lefttab>") 'elscreen-previous)
```

see also [Buffer Management](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Buffer_management) and specially ibuffer if your goal is to list all available buffers (which you can do now with the menu).

Answer (score 1):

Try my package centaur-tabs. I tried to make it as modern looking as I could, providing a lot of customization options and theming it in popular theme packages like Kaolin Themes or Atom One Dark Theme. It is keyboard oriented although the tabs work with the mouse. It is available in MELPA, try it out and feel free to contribute or submit any kind of feedback. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1N5C.png)

Comment: Looks nice, but couldn't install it due to some other package not found `powerline-20190323.213.tar: Not found`

Answer (score 1):

As [of 2019](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=2698d3dba2e9858b026ed127d4de3f86810a5ef3) Emacs [now has native tabs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tab-Line.html), so

`(global-tab-line-mode t)`

Answer (score 0):

I find <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd>
([`list-buffers`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/List-Buffers.html))
combined with <kbd>o</kbd> (`Buffer-menu-other-window`, try also
<kbd>?</kbd> for detailed help) perfectly adequate.

Others use
[Speedbar](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Speedbar.html)
which is *way* more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You have several choices:

- [speedbar](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeedBar): <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>speedbar</kbd>
- [ibuffer](http://martinowen.net/blog/2010/02/03/tips-for-emacs-ibuffer.html): <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>ibuffer</kbd>
- or even simply using helm: <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>helm-buffer-list</kbd>